# How long could Earth's oxygen supply last if no new oxygen were produced?

Tags: photosynthesis

I read in an article or heard in some documentary that there's so much oxygen in the atmosphere that even if all photosynthesis stopped, there's already enough to last us a long time.

Is this correct? Why or why not? If so, how long is this 'long time', roughly? I've seen estimates between 15,000 to 150,000 years.

Comment: Interesting question (although it may be off-topic as there is not a clear specific answer). Where have you seen those estimates?

Comment: @James this isn't Skeptic Stack Exchange, supplying sources for my claims doesnt matter, the question is simple and clear. Everyone else was able to conprehend it just fine.

Comment: This isn't skeptics SE, but I am a skeptic. I wanted that reference specifically because it might have provided some objective insight or approach *(personally I think the below answers so far are very subjective to what one considers "reasonable estimates")*. More generally though, you should support your claims appropriately, [not only in your answers](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3334/when-are-citations-needed-in-an-answer/3336#3336) but your questions too. Else we end up in [this situation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1j2Duy_xzEA).

Answer (score 5):

**Disclaimer:**

This is going to be a very mathematical answer. Before answering it, I assume that you are only asking about humans, assuming that all other organisms don't require $O_2$ to survive (as it will complicate the answer many many times).

**List of variables:**

```
V     = total volume of air on earth (in l)
V'    = total volume of oxygen on earth (in l)
V(1)  = volume of oxygen used by 1 person in whole lifetime (in l)
V(a)  = volume of oxygen used by whole mankind (one generation) in whole lifetime (in l)
V(p)  = percentage of total oxygen used by whole mankind (one generation) in whole lifetime
```

**Method used:**

$ \%\hspace{1mm}Volume\hspace{1mm}of\hspace{1mm}O_2\hspace{1mm}used\hspace{1mm}per\hspace{1mm}generation = \underline{\hspace{3mm}Volume\hspace{5mm}of\hspace{5mm}O_2\hspace{5mm}in\hspace{5mm}air\hspace{3mm}}\times\hspace{1mm}100$
$\hspace{83mm}Volume\hspace{1mm}of\hspace{1mm}O_2\hspace{1mm}used\hspace{1mm}by\hspace{1mm}humans$

$Number\hspace{1mm}of\hspace{1mm}years = \underline{\hspace{2mm}Number\hspace{1mm}of\hspace{1mm}years\hspace{1mm}in\hspace{1mm}1\hspace{1mm}generation\hspace{2mm}}$
$\hspace{42mm}\%\hspace{1mm}Volume\hspace{1mm}of\hspace{1mm}O_2\hspace{1mm}used\hspace{1mm}per\hspace{1mm}generation$

**Procedure:**

Lets first find out the total amount of air on earth.

From [this](http://boingboing.net/2008/03/11/all-the-water-and-ai.html):

> The air sphere measures 1999 kilometres across and weighs 5140 trillion tonnes.

From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_of_air):

> At sea level and at 15 °C air has a density of approximately 1.225 kg/m3

Total volume of air:

$volume = mass \hspace{1mm} / \hspace{1mm} density$

$V = 5140 \times 10^{12} \hspace{1mm} tonnes \hspace{1mm} / \hspace{1mm} 1.225 \hspace{1mm} kg.m^{-3}$

$V = 4195.9 \times 10^3 \times 10^{12} \hspace{1mm} m^3$

$V = 4195.9 \times 10^3 \times 10^{12} \times 10^3 \hspace{1mm} l$

$V = 4195.9 \times 10^{18} \hspace{1mm} l$

Now, from [this](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/air-composition-d_212.html), 20.95% of this is $O_2$ i.e.

$V' = 4195.9 \times 10^{18} \times 20.95 / 100$

$V' = 87904.489 \times 10^{16}$

$V' = 879.04 \times 10^{18} \hspace{1mm} l$

Moving on to next part, from [this](http://health.howstuffworks.com/human-body/systems/respiratory/question98.htm):

> a human being uses about 550 liters of pure oxygen per day.

From [this](http://www.who.int/gho/mortality_burden_disease/life_tables/situation_trends/en/):

> 71 years was the average life expectancy at birth of the global population in 2013.

$V_1 = 550 \hspace{1mm} l.day^{-1}.person^{-1} \times 25915 \hspace{1mm} days$

$V_1= 142.53 \times 10^5 \hspace{1mm} l.person^{-1}$

From [this](http://www.worldometers.info/world-population/):

> The world population (the total number of living humans on Earth) was 7.349 billion as of July 1, 2015.

So

$V_{a} = 142.53 \times 10^5 \hspace{1mm} l.person^{-1} \times 7.349 \times 10^9 people$

$V_{a} = 1047.452 \times 10^{14} \hspace{1mm} l$

Finally

$V_p = V_a / V' \times 100$

$V_p = (1047.452 \times 10^{14}) / (879.04 \times 10^{18}) \times 100$

$V_p = 1.191 \times 10^{-2}$

$V_p = 0.0191 \hspace{1mm} \% $

This gives the percentage of total $O_2$ in air used by one human generation. From this, we can find the number of years for which $O_2$ will last, as I have done below:

$25,915 \hspace{1mm} days = 71 \hspace{1mm} years$

$71 \hspace{1mm} years = 0.0191 \hspace{1mm} \%$

$1 \hspace{1mm} \% = 71 / 0.0191 \hspace{1mm} years$

$100 \hspace{1mm} \% = 3717.277 \times 100 \hspace{1mm} years$

$\hspace{13mm} = 371,727.748 \hspace{1mm} years$

**Conclusion:**

So, yes at least humans can live for a very long time without plants doing any photosynthesis (ideally). 371,727 years seems too large a period of time, but it is just based on ideal assumptions, this number would come down (maybe into your specified range) when more variables are added.

**For example:**

To show extent of deviation by addition of factors, I add a very general, but complex factor in the expression: *air pollution*.

How much $CO_2$ is released per year can be estimated from [this](http://www.ucsusa.org/clean_energy/coalvswind/c02c.html#.VzXZg9R97s0):

> In 2011, utility coal plants in the United States emitted a total of 1.7 billion tons of CO2

And with the contribution of countries like China, India, Europe, etc. that number should rise up to at least 2.5 million tonnes (its just that I couldn't find the worldwide data on it).

Now:

$1 \hspace{1mm} C + 1 \hspace{1mm} O_2 \rightarrow 1 \hspace{1mm} CO_2$

$2.5 \times 10^9 \hspace{1mm} kg \hspace{1mm} CO_2 \Rightarrow 2.5 \times 10^9 \hspace{1mm} kg \hspace{1mm} O_2$

So, 2.5 million tonnes more $O_2$ is being used each year from the environment. But, there is another twist in this. From [this](http://www.who.int/mediacentre/news/releases/2014/air-pollution/en/):

> WHO reports that in 2012 around 7 million people died - one in eight of total global deaths – as a result of air pollution exposure.

It means that 7 million people less will consume $O_2$ each year i.e.

$Net \hspace{1mm} population = 7349 \times 10^6 - 7 \times 10^6$

$\hspace{32mm} = 7.342 \times 10^9$

$V_{a} = 142.53 \times 10^5 \times 7.342 \times 10^9$

$V_{a} = 1046.455 \times 10^{14} \hspace{1mm} l$

$V_p = V_a / V' \times 100$

$V_p = (1046.455 \times 10^{14}) / (879.04 \times 10^{18}) \times 100$

$V_p = 1.1904 \times 10^{-2}$

$V_p = 0.01904 \hspace{1mm} \% $

$25,915 \hspace{1mm} days = 71 \hspace{1mm} years$

$71 \hspace{1mm} years = 0.01904 \hspace{1mm} \%$

$1 \hspace{1mm} \% = 71 / 0.01904 \hspace{1mm} years$

$100 \hspace{1mm} \% = 3728.991 \times 100 \hspace{1mm} years$

$\hspace{13mm} = 372,899.159 \hspace{1mm} years$

So, overall number increases instead of decreasing. This example was just to show how adding more factors to the equation would deviate the overall answer, and how large that deviation can be.

Comment: an average of 30'000 days = 82 years, is way too high to be seen as an accurate estimation. According the the WHO it is more around 71 years/ or 25'915 days

Comment: @JordiZambrino it was just an assumption that I heard about in a TV show. Its just that I couldn't find an appropriate reference for this, but thanks for telling that :)

Comment: Average age is just a guess. We can change it and won't change answer much. Main thing is to include stochastic factors - especially pollution and I would like to know how much it will skew the answers

Comment: @TalhaIrfan as I said in the answer, adding such factors would complicate the situation to a large extent, but I don't think that polluting gases would have any effect on the amount of O2 in the environment, yeah but burning of fuels would surely do. Anyways, I'll try to add it in the answer :)

Comment: @TalhaIrfan I hope this helps. I wouldn't be shocked to see you shocked with the answer because I am already shocked by the answer, I mean just see how shocking is that ;)

Comment: My first response was: I don't want to live on this planet anymore ;) Man!! What a research and effort you put behind this answer. I am shocked this answer hasn't got the upvotes yet it deserved. One of the best answers I saw on this website in these 2 years. Awesome!

Comment: 10/10 for effort. Am I right in pointing out that two critical assumptions undermine the estimate? 1.everything else stops besides humans, 2.the population stays the same.

Comment: @James yes you are correct. I am not good in calculus, so I solved it by using these assumptions and as I said in answer, such variables would deviate the answer to a large extent (I don't even know if it can be solved using calculus also). Did you give the downvote BTW?

Comment: @another'Homosapien' It was my vote **:(** (*but you shouldn't really ask specifically as it [probably isn't the person that comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121350/ive-just-been-downvoted-how-should-i-react)*). I think that whilst you do make a real effort to point out the deviation, there are too many unreasonable assumptions for the answer to be useful. The most valuable part of the answer is "Who knows?" not "372,899.159 years". Note I voted to close the question because it inevitably demands answers that make a lot of assumptions that are subjectively "reasonable".

Comment: @James thanks for pointing it out, I just wanted to give OP an idea about large or small this value can get, how hard it might get to find exact value, and how OP can calculate a much more accurate value by themselves (in vacations ;)

Answer (score 2):

The answer above gives a nice calculation how much oxygen there is, and how much we use. There are some BIG other factors that warrant a second answer IMO.

Starting at 371 thousand years (above).

- Animals: according to http://xkcd.com/1338/ (probably sourced somewhere reliable) humans make up only ~20% of the walking biomass, so we would burn through the oxygen supply 5 times faster.
- Fuels: my guess for an average fuel consumption would be around 5 metric tons per annum (http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/EN.ATM.CO2E.PC/countries, 17 metric tons of CO2 per annum for the USA, 1,7 for India). To get 5 tons of CO2 we need 3,6 tons of O2. From the above calculation I calculate that we use 245 kg per year of O2, so for our fuel we need 15 times more oxygen than for breathing.

That leaves us with around 5000 years to live. However, from http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/co2-comfort-level-d_1024.html I guesstimate that above something like 1-5% CO2 is not survivable on the long term, leaving us with only 250-1250 years to leave before we slowly suffocate.

Of course we would die long before that from starvation.

Comment: You can't go on burning fuels when the oxygen content of the air drops below a certain percentage. I haven't got a reference for that, but I would guess that around 15%, rather than 20%, oxygen concentration, it would be pretty hard to ignite hydrocarbons.

Comment: Didn't think of that (but it's the same with breathing of course). With methane you'd need only 12% oxygen: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limiting_oxygen_concentration